# MailKit : search if custom header exists

Tags: mailkit

I have added a custom header in emails, conditionally

and I want using the IMAP/SearchQuery to return only  the mails having the   header.

Not its value, only to return true/false if the header exists.

Is it possible ?  thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to rfc3501 (the IMAP specification):

```
HEADER <field-name> <string>
         Messages that have a header with the specified field-name (as
         defined in [RFC-2822]) and that contains the specified string
         in the text of the header (what comes after the colon).  If the
         string to search is zero-length, this matches all messages that
         have a header line with the specified field-name regardless of
         the contents.
```

To make this search in MailKit, what you would do is this:

```
var results = folder.Search (SearchQuery.Header ("X-Custom-Header", string.Empty));
```

Edit:

I just discovered a logic bug in MailKit that would decide to send empty strings as ATOMs instead of QSTRING like it should. I've fixed this in [git master](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), but have not made a release yet. I'll probably do that this weekend.

Comment: $imap->search($mboxes, "HEADER X-my-header \"\"");